# Bash Script Check for Multiple Directories

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to write a bash script and part of the script is to check for multiple directories and if the directories don't exist then make them. Can someone help me on this?

The directories look like this

```
EX: /mk1 /mk2 /mk3 /mk4 ... /mk22
```

I have the make the directory part.

```
"else mkdir {/mk1../mk22}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't know how to increment complex alphanumeric strings. You have to "factor out" the alphabetic part so that you can iterate over the solely numeric part.

```
mkdir -p /mk{1..22}
```

The `-p` tell `mkdir` to make the directory if necessary, so you don't have to check if they exist first.